# Java Spring MVC get list of requested mappings, or maybe views

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In terms of basic web-development, I've previously done some basic things in WordPress so I'm still getting used to Spring MVC and learning some of the equivalents.

In WordPress I was able to get a list of the Pages that I created. I could then take that list, print it to the page and format it with css (Like a navbar). Is there something similar I can do in my controller? Can I get a list of my mapped paths that I can pass to my views or am I on a fool's errand? (Unfortunately I haven't found anything alluding to what I need to do in my various google searches)

Thanks to any in advance who can steer me in the right direction.

Comment: This is, unfortunately for you, not a *steering* community. What is possible depends on your own skill set. I think the spring reference documentation is the best place to start. http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may scan all the cotrollers defined in the application using [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html) and Filtering it with [Controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) annotation.

Here is the complete code:

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Controller.class));
        for (BeanDefinition beanDef : scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.xxx.yyy.controllers")){
            System.out.println(beanDef.getBeanClassName());
        }
```

By further drilldown, you may get all the request mapping you have in the controller.

Comment: This definitely answered my question, but I realized I was asking the right question for the wrong problem. I'm getting more comfortable with spring and instead of doing this I implemented apache site tiles. So I could reference the pages I wanted and format them.